# google cloud speech to text rest api return empty response

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I tried to use google cloud speech to text API, by using the sample page (https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/). It works fine after I upload my audio file (.m4a)

Then I try to call these services using rest API and the same audio file, it does not work.

I get 200 with an empty response.

I call rest API with this info

POST https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize?key=SOME_KEY

body:

```
{
  "audio": {
    "content": "base64 audio content"
  },
  "config": {
    "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
    "encoding": "LINEAR16",
    "languageCode": "en-US"
  }
}
```

but on https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/, the body is different a little bit like this

```
{
  "audio": {
    "content": "/* Your audio */"
  },
  "config": {
    "enableAutomaticPunctuation": true,
    "encoding": "LINEAR16",
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "model": "default"
  }
}
```

I don't know why it does not work when calling rest API.

Please help

Updated =>

I read audio file by this code (example from google doc)

```
const file = fs.readFileSync('FILE_LOCATION')
const audioBytes = file.toString('base64')
```

Comment: Can you expand on how you are supplying your audio data?   If you are supplying it inline, are you base64 encoding it?  If so, how?

Comment: @Kolban i have added the example of reading file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the docs, I could find no reference to ".m4a" (Apple Lossless) files being supported by Google Text To Speech.  In fact, quite the reverse.

What I'd suggest is, at a minimum, try converting your file to a WAV format file and supplying that.  If that works, see if you can't get your raw audio in such a format.

See:

- [Convert speech from an audio file to text using Google Speech API](https://medium.com/cod3/convert-speech-from-an-audio-file-to-text-using-google-speech-api-b951f4032a64)
- [Audio Encoding](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/RecognitionConfig#AudioEncoding)

Comment: thanks, i convert my file to .wav and it works fine now.